# Has anyone tried to add sqlalchemy admin to FastAPI router instead of main?

Tags: authentication, dependencies

I have tried to add sqlalchemy admin to a FastAPI router since it was mentioned as full functional app ( the router ), by trying this

```py
admin_router = APIRouter(prefix="/admin")
admin = Admin(admin_router, engine, base_url="/admin_panel")
admin.add_view(LessonAdmin)
```

However, sqlalchemy admin wants to use

```py
admin = Admin(app, engine, base_url="/admin_panel")
admin.add_view(LessonAdmin)
```

syntax or it does no show.
The reason why I wanted to add it to a router rather than main is I have already implemented authorization and it's working nice.
Something like..

```py
user_router.include_router(
    lessons.router, dependencies=[Security(get_current_active_user)]
)
```

gives me all the authorization with necessary scopes.
It would be very easy this way.
Anyone has tried it? ( the sqlalchemy admin )

I tried to attach sqlalchemy admin to a router instead of main app.
Admin did not show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about [`sqladmin`](https://aminalaee.dev/sqladmin/), it technically operates on a `Starlette` instance (of which `FastAPI` is a subclass), so it's not gonna work with an `APIRouter`. Since it uses `Starlette`, it won't trigger FastAPI dependencies either way. You probably implement your authentication in [`sqladmin`'s authentication](https://aminalaee.dev/sqladmin/api_reference/authentication/), or reimplement yours as a middleware.